# How to correctly update an Image in a JLabel?

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, jlabel

I'm French so my English is quite bad but I have a real problem with java:
I'm trying to show an Image built manually with some `fillRect` & co.

It works. Next, I want to update this image as a function of the text I enter in the text field. And there is the problem: it doesn't change anything, and if I manually rescale the window of the `JFrame`, the image shows totally deformed or scaled badly.

I'm a beginner and I have difficulties with GUI, moreso when I want to couple it with Images.

Can you help me? Why doesn't it work as I want? This is my code below, a bit long but actually quite simple ! Thanks :)

---

**I've changed it a bit, this is the 2e VERSION.**

Now the problem s that I can't change a condition in order to modify the color of a simple rectangle, try "lol" in the entry field !

### CODE VERSION 2

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Fenetre extends JFrame {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel container = new JPanel();
    private JTextField jtf;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Commandes   ");
    private JButton b = new JButton ("OK");
    private Graphics graph;
    private Image img;
    private JLabel screen;
    private boolean color;

    /**
     * Constructeur de l'objet 
     */
    public Fenetre(){
        color = true;


        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Animation");
        frame.setSize(1000, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        container.setBackground(Color.white);
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        JPanel top = new JPanel();

        jtf = new JTextField();

        jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 30));

        b.addActionListener(new BoutonListener());

        frame.setContentPane(top);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

        paintComponent(graph);

        screen = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(img));

        top.add(screen);
        top.add(label);
        top.add(jtf);
        top.add(b);

        frame.setContentPane(top);
     }      


    class BoutonListener implements ActionListener{ 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(jtf.getText().equals("lol")) lol();
                System.out.println("Entry  : " + jtf.getText());
        }  
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if(img == null) {
            img = frame.createImage(1000,300);
            g = img.getGraphics();
        }
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0,0,1000,300);
        if(color) g.setColor(Color.orange); else g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(8,25,200,100);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawString("Text",10,10);
    }

    public void lol()
    {
        if(color) color = false; else color = true;
    }
}
```

---

### PREVIOUS CODE

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Fenetre extends JFrame {

    private JPanel container = new JPanel();
    private JTextField jtf;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Commandes   ");
    private JButton b = new JButton ("OK");
    private Graphics g;
    private Image img;
    private JLabel screen;

    /**
     * Constructeur de l'objet 
     */
    public Fenetre(){

        this.setTitle("Animation");
        this.setSize(1000, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        container.setBackground(Color.white);
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        JPanel top = new JPanel();

        jtf = new JTextField();

        jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 30));

        b.addActionListener(new BoutonListener());

        this.setContentPane(top);
        this.setVisible(true); 

        paint(g);

        screen = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(img));

        top.add(screen);
        top.add(label);
        top.add(jtf);
        top.add(b);


        this.setContentPane(top);
     }      


    class BoutonListener implements ActionListener{ 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Entry  : " + jtf.getText());
                if(jtf.getText().equals("lol")) lol();
        }  
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if(img == null) {
            img = createImage(1000,300);
            g = img.getGraphics();
        }
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0,0,1000,300);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(8,25,200,100);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawString("Text",10,10);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(8,25,300,100);
    }

    public void lol()
    {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(8,25,200,100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several problems in your code:

1. You are confusing your `g` member variable with the `g` parameter of the `paint` method. When `lol` is called, `g` is `null` and you get a `NullPointerException`
2. You should never grab a hold on `Graphics` (only in really rare cases). Instead you override properly `paintComponent()` and you use the `Graphics` parameter to draw what you want. When you want to update the component, you call `repaint()`
3. Don't override `paint`, but override `paintComponent()`
4. Don't override `paint` of `JFrame`. Use a dedicate component for that. No need to use a JLabel for that, a simple `JComponent` is enough.
5. Don't extend `JFrame` if you are not extending its functionality.
6. After adding components to the component hierarchy, call `revalidate()`

Fix those issues and come back with another question if you still have problems.

You should probably consider reading [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html) and the few next steps. It will show you basic examples of things similar to what you are trying to do.

EDIT:
I took your V2 code and patched it as I could. This is very far from perfect but you should get the gist of how you can do this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Fenetre extends JComponent {

    private boolean color;

    /**
     * Constructeur de l'objet
     */
    public Fenetre() {
        color = true;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 300));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 300);
        if (color) {
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
        }
        g.fillRect(8, 25, 200, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawString("Text", 10, 10);
    }

    public void lol() {
        if (color) {
            color = false;
        } else {
            color = true;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    protected static void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Animation");
        frame.setSize(1000, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        final JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
        final Fenetre fenetre = new Fenetre();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Commandes   ");
        JButton b = new JButton("OK");
        container.setBackground(Color.white);
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 30));
        class BoutonListener implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (jtf.getText().equals("lol")) {
                    fenetre.lol();
                }
                System.out.println("Entry  : " + jtf.getText());
            }
        }
        b.addActionListener(new BoutonListener());

        top.add(fenetre);
        top.add(label);
        top.add(jtf);
        top.add(b);
        top.revalidate();
        frame.setContentPane(top);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Congratulations, for touching that magical figure of 10,000 :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now the image is properly shown, the only problem is that when I launch `lol()` with the command "lol" in the entry field, I just tried to change the color of the rectangle, but it doesn't and it returns an error as a NullPointerException (no text?)

PS : I let extends `JFrame` for the repaint() method.
I don't understand the meaning of the method `revalidate`

Comment: @Mizur revalidate needs to be called so that components added to the hierarchy are laid out. Never call paintComponent yourself, simply call repaint(). I will add an updated version of your code to my post, because there are really many problems in your code.

Comment: @Mizur: you should "accept" this answer by clicking on the large check mark to the left of it.

Comment: Actually there is one problem more : the InitUI(() method is static, so all of my methods must be static too. It is a bit annoying !

Comment: @Mizur I don't know why all your methods must be static. Simply use `new` and call instance methods. What you may need is to create additional classes. Anyway, you are right to avoid static methods. Here my attempt was more to show how to use painting in Swing from your code rather than showing how to structure your code for Swing. NB: I also added the missing call to `super.paintComponent`, this is really important.

Comment: Thanks ! Actually the problem is that in this class `Fenetre` , `main()` is static, so `InitUI()` too. After that, I create a new class to control the graphics shown by this first class `Fenetre`. BUT : The image and the Graphics used in `Fenetre` are also static ! I don't manage to modify it trought another class : it is said to be static (the Image and the Graphics), so i can't transform them.

Comment: @Mizur You don't need to hold a Graphics nor an Image as I posted in the code above. If you still have references to a Graphics, then this is really going to be problematic. Also, I don't see why your Graphics and Image in Fenetre should be static. Anyway, I would suggest to post another question if you are still stuck. Possibly, post your code with your `static` and ask how to get rid of them properly.

Comment: You are right ! i've posted it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791346/some-trouble-with-paintcomponent ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your Swing graphics programming has several significant problems, and I urge you to go through the tutorials to learn how to do this better.  For example, you are

- calling the paint method directly -- something you should almost never do except in very special situations (this is not one of them)
- Drawing directly in the JFrame's `paint(...)` method. Instead you will want to draw in the `paintComponent(...)` method override of a class derived from JComponent such as JPanel.
- Calling update unnecessarily as if this were an AWT program. You don't do this in Swing unless you're changing the Look & Feel.

Again, take a look at the tutorials on this -- you will not regret doing this, trust me.

edit -- too slow! 1+ to Guillaume

Comment: Thanks ! I answer just to the other answer, following your advices too :D